# Problem on family of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X_i$ be family of normed linear spaces(i=1,2.... )Let $X=\{(x_i)\mid x_i\in X_i\}$ and $\sum\|x_i\|^{p}_{X_i} < \infty$. Put a norm on $X$ by
$\left(\sum\|x_i\|^{p}_{X_i}\right)^{1/p}$ where p$\geq$1 . Then $X$ is a Banach space if and only if each $X_{i}$ is a Banach space.

I got the converse whose argument is quite similar to how we showed $l_{p}$ is Banach but I am stuck on implies part.

I'd like to have some help about that.

Comment: Oops..let me edit

Comment: What's going wrong in coding:(.

Comment: Just edited, but it is merely a first step. Pls improve on the title ("family of Banach" vs. "family of normed ..." in the question body), clarify the range for $p$, and where  the index $i$ lives.

Comment: And formulate a concise question to make clear what you expect from an answer. Actually there's none.

Comment: Hint: suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X_1$, then consider the sequence $(x_n, 0, 0, \ldots)$ in $X$...

Comment: @ Theo Bendit.. Wow..I got it

Comment: @Hanno Thanks..I will remember your remarks.